# Does Microsoft Graph API for OneDrive for Business have the ability to filter on file extensions yet?

Tags: c#, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I am coding against the `Microsoft Graph CSharp SDK` and I have been working on proofing out the ability to filter on file extensions for OneDrive for Business. So far all the articles I have read seem to say that this feature is not **yet** baked into the `Microsoft Graph API`.

Since most of these articles are based out in 2011, I just wanted to ask if this had been addressed or if there is a workaround that anyone has implemented with success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

So after digging a bit more into the docs and playing around in my sandbox application, I was able to create an internal class which consisted of different strings which I passed into the `.Search()` and construct my request as so:

`await graphServiceClient.Drives[custodianAct].Search(".txt").Request().GetAsync();`

Which will return all the `DriveSearchCollectionPage` objects that match with the given file extension.